# $_GET não pega "+"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu estou recuperando um valor de uma requisição AJAX, funciona perfeito porém tem um problema. O caractere "+" é substituído por um em branco

```
Dell printer (supporting eSF 2.1+)
```

Fica

```
Dell printer (supporting eSF 2.1 )
```

E isso está dando "bomba" no sistema

```
 var XMLHttp =  generateXMLHttp();
    XMLHttp.open("get", "classes/getDataPropCom.php?qtd_embarcados=" + qtdUsuarios +"&id=" + id, true);
    XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4){
            if (XMLHttp.status == 200) {
            }
        }
});
```

O jquery pega o valor com o "+" certinho
Agora o resgate do GET do Ajax não pega o "+"

**Quando ele chega aqui.... não pega o "+"**

```
if(isset($_GET['qtd_embarcados']) && isset($_GET['id'])){
    $qtd_embarcados = $_GET['qtd_embarcados'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    if($qtd_embarcados != ''){
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            /* special ajax here */
            $PropostaComercial->getValue($qtd_embarcados,$id);
        }else if(empty($usuarios)){
            $PropostaComercial->getValue($qtd_embarcados,$id);
        }
        else{
            $PropostaComercial->getValue($qtd_embarcados,$id);
        }
    }
}
```

**como eu pego os valores**

```
 if($("#ComercialEDEP10 h5").html() != undefined){
        id = encodeURIComponent($("#ComercialEDEP10 h5").html());
    }

    if($("#EducacionalEDEP10 h5").html() != undefined){
        id = encodeURIComponent($("#EducacionalEDEP10 h5").html());
    }
    if($("#ProfissionalEDEP10 h5").html() != undefined){
        id = encodeURIComponent($("#ProfissionalEDEP10 h5").html());
    }
```

Comment: Esse texto com o `+` vem do servidor ou vai para o servidor?

Comment: É um valor do banco de dados, que exibo na tela, uma vez exibido na tela, pego o conteúdo dele, uma vez pegado envio via ajax para rodar em um sql

Comment: Mas então o problema está quando recebes do servidor ou quando envias de volta?

Comment: Tipo, eu transfiro via ajax... nesse ajax pega legal, ai quando o php com o $_GET[] vai pegar o valor que da o erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de tratar essa string antes de enviar para o ajax.

```js
var string = 'Dell printer (supporting eSF 2.1+)';
var stringTratada = encodeURIComponent(string);

console.log(stringTratada);
```

Assim não se perdem caracteres e fica num formato normalizado.

E no PHP se necessário (pois o `$_GET` já faz isso) podes usar [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php) para converter de novo para a string legível.

Comment: Só no php não tem jeito ne?

Comment: @gabrielfalieri no browser o `+` está lá, certo? então tens de enviar isso para o servidor e caracteres como espaço em branco e alguns simbolos como o `+` não são permitidos sem serem convertidos. Daí o `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: sim sim, isso mesmo

Comment: Porquê `.html()` e não `.text()`? E o que dá `console.log("classes/getDataPropCom.php?qtd_embarcados=" + qtdUsuarios +"&id=" + id);`?